# how to fix this error, its happen whene i'm trying to build .apk from react-native project

Tags: android, react-native

this is the error that i'm getting whene i'm trying to build .apk with `./gradlew assembleDebug` commande in my `android` directory from `react-native` project thanks for any suggestions and help

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-community_masked-view'.
> No signature of method: build_9xydcf3yl2vrrdybqldni6i35.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_9xydcf3yl2vrrdybqldni6i35$_run_closure1) values: [build_9xydcf3yl2vrrdybqldni6i35$_run_closure1@161d1d4]
```

and my `build.gradle` looks like this :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = 30
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

i don't know what is went wrong, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Please provide buildToolsVersion value as `string` instead of the `number` in ./build.gradle file
`buildToolsVersion='28.0.0'`
instead of
`buildToolsVersion=28`